# how to get results from database by wpdb using array

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to get results by using array query like `$wpdb->update or $wpdb->delete`?

I think it's secure and easy to use.

Example :

```
$wpdb->get_results("products", ['order' => 1, 'user' => 2]);
```

Comment: Really very unclear what you are trying to ask here. Are you maybe looking for https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/ …?

Comment: Sorry for bad english. What i'm trying to ask is how to use wpdb to select rows by arguments, just like WP_Query. get_posts is good example but it's only work for one table and it's fields. i use custom tables like products, orders and etc...

Comment: I don’t think there is a way to do that. The purpose of wpdb is to make low-level database queries by directly writing the SQL yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try query like below:

```
    global $wpdb;
    $ids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title ='test' AND post_type='product' AND post_status='publish'");
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i know how to use $wpdb methods but my point is how to use it to select rows by arguments, just like WP_Query. I think it's secure and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I write a function who do it for me but i wonder if wordpress itself have a way for this.

```
Public Function Select_Rows($Table, $Arguments) {
    IF ( Empty($Arguments) OR !Is_Array($Arguments) ) { Return False; }

    $Query = "Select * From "  . $Table . " Where ";

    ForEach ( $Arguments As $Key => $Value ) {
        $Value  = Esc_SQL($Value);
        $Key    = Esc_SQL($Key);

        $Query .= $Key . "='" . $Value . "' And ";
    }

    $Query = SubStr($Query, 0, -5);

    Return $this->DB->Get_Results($Query);
}
```

$this->DB is $wpdb